# php, curl_exec response return additional info aside from json

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm currently using gifs.com API with php using CUrl but the response I get isn't pure JSON

The code below is the response i get from `curl_exec()`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx Date: Thu, 02 Nov 2017 16:34:48 GMT Content-
Type: application/json Content-Length: 472 Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: 
false Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Accept,Content-Type,Gifs-API-Key 
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 
* Access-Control-Max-Age: 43200 Request-Id: 942c0be8-0613-4c43-8fc0-
fbedf62e7008 Via: 1.1 google Alt-Svc: clear 
{ "success": 
    { "page": "https://gifs.com/gif/9QQDvZ", 
      "oembed": "https://gifs.com/oembed/9QQDvZ", 
      "embed": "<iframe src='https://gifs.com/embed/9QQDvZ' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' width='377' height='377' style='-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;-webkit-transform: scale(1);' ></iframe>", 
        "files": { 
          "gif": "https://j.gifs.com/9QQDvZ.gif", 
          "jpg": "https://j.gifs.com/9QQDvZ.jpg", 
          "mp4": "https://j.gifs.com/9QQDvZ.mp4" } 
      } 
}
```

`json_decode()` will just return null if i use it on the response, and i tried `substr()` to remove the extra characters but that wouldn't be consistent since the amount of characters will keep changing

**EDIT**

below is the curl configuration

```
  $url = 'https://api.gifs.com/media/import';
  $headers = array("Gifs-API-Key: willnotbedisplayed", "Content-Type: application/json"); // cURL headers for file uploading
  $postfields = "{\n \"source\": \"willnotbedisplayed\",\n \"title\": \"guineapig\",\n \"tags\": [\"crazy\", \"hand drawn\", \"2015\", \"art\"],\n \"attribution\": {\n   \"site\": \"vine\",\n   \"user\": \"someone\"\n }\n}";
  $ch = curl_init();
  $options = array(
      CURLOPT_URL => $url,
      CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
      CURLOPT_POST => 1,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
  ); // cURL options
  curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
  $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Can  you add your curl configuration? For example: did you add `curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true)`?

Comment: @TVproductions i added the configuration now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you used:

```
CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
```

That tells `curl` to include the HTTP headers in the output.

Get rid of that.